# In a complete Riemannian manifold $M$, do any two points $p,q\in M$ admit a length minimizing geodesic?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations

Clearly, completeness gives us the existence of at least one geodesic $\gamma:[0,1]\to M$ such that $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma(1)=q$, however, this geodesic need not be length minimizing. I strongly suspect length minimizing geodesics must exist, but I can't quite construct the argument for their existence in full detail. This is what I've come up with.

If we let $r=d(p,q)$, and $U= B(p,2r)\cup B(q,2r)$, then by completeness, $U$ is a precompact open in $M$. If we define $\Gamma$ to be the set of smooth (or sufficiently regular) paths $\gamma:[0,1]\to M$ with b.c. $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma(1)=q$, and define $\Gamma_0\subset \Gamma$ to contain those paths $\gamma $ with image in $\overline U$, then we may apply the direct method of calculus of variations to minimize the energy functional
$$
E:\Gamma\to\mathbb R,\quad E[\gamma]=\int_0^1\! |\dot\gamma(t)|\,\mathrm dt.
$$
To do so, we define a weak topology on $\Gamma$ under which $\Gamma_0$ is weakly compact and $E$ is lower-semicontinuous, so that we may obtain a geodesic of minimal length.

The tricky thing here, of course, is to find a suitable weak topology, on a suitable candidate space $\Gamma$, such as $H^1(0,1;M)$ with boundary conditions. Naïvely, I would $H^1(0,1;M)$ to suffice, with a weak topology defined via coordinate charts, but before going through the calculations, I'm wondering if there's already a reference for this result, with a clean proof.

Comment: This fact is usually included as part of the Hopf-Rinow theorem, so you can find a (relatively) elementary proof in many introductory texts in Riemannian geometry. For example, it is the very first part of Hopf-Rinow addressed by Do Carmo in theorem 2.8.

Answer (score 1):

Jurgen Jost also gives a proof in *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis*, chapter 1.5. It's only for compact manifolds (complete manifolds are in chapter 1.7), but you already figured out how to deal with this problem.

In short, it's enough to take $\Gamma$ as the class of Lipschitz curves $\gamma \colon [0,1] \to U$ with constant speed. One can easily modify such curves to be piecewise geodesic, and then the compactness argument is very elementary, since every curve is represented just by a finite collection of points.